# Highchart Bar table tooltip dissapears on hovering the tooltip

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

Highcharts is a JS API that allows you to easily generate bar charts. The above link shows a Highchart stacked column table. The bars show some information in a tooltip when you hover on them. Highchart allows us to control the delay of the tooltip with this JS parameter **hideDelay: number** but there is no such parameter to hold the tooltip when you hover on it.

What I want is to make the tooltip stay even when I hover on it. Tooltip only stays when I hover on the bars and disappears a few minutes after I take my cursor away from the bar.

Comment: Please provide more details, what have you tried, maybe some code examples. Also try to tag your question (I guess it concerns javascript)

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

Here, hover over the bar and then hover on the tooltip. the tooltip will disappear. I don't want it to disappear. The highchart api provides option to delay the tooltip but nothing else.

Comment: Ok, please edit your question and provide more details

Comment: more detail provided, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set plotOptions.series.column.stickyTracking to true.

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        stickyTracking: true
    }
},
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e4d8z297/)

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.stickyTracking

Comment: Here in Stack Overflow community, you can simply say "thank you" by accepting the answer (if it's correct) and giving upvote ;)